# Issue with .csv file in Rstudio

Tags: csv, rstudio, workspace

I started a data analysis class where I use R and Rstudio. I'm currently dealing with an issue regarding .csv file: I have a file named "andore_2019.csv" located in a certain path in my Windows. When I search this .csv file with my Windows file explorer I find it. But when I use Rstudio, this file isn't visible in my workspace. I attach 2 pictures so you can see the issue. May someone help me, please?

[image]

[image]

Best regards,

I tried to desinstall and reinstall R and Rstudio. I just want to see my .csv files when I search in my Rstudio workspace. It seems that I can only see .R o .Rdata files.

Comment: There is a difference in folders as well. Given the cloud icon is it possible that what you find via file explorer is a cloud folder that hasn't syncronized locally?

Comment: Use the Rstudio Project feature.

Answer (score 0):

First check the working directory

```
getwd()
```

then set it to required path

```
setwd("your path")
```

I have had similar issue in the past where file name length is too long in the past changing the file path to a shorter name has worked.

Comment: I changed the path and now I see my file. It seems that shortening the path worked. Thank you